# Handle View permissions in BaseController

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Pages table that stores all my view urls and this table has permissions linked to the user's role.  My controllers inherit of a BaseController so I was wondering where I intercept the request and then return a InvalidPermissions view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to override [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting.aspx) or [OnAuthorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onauthorization.aspx), depending on what is available and what you need from the request/controller context.  You might also want to think about using a custom [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) or deriving from [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) as a means to make it more flexible for each action/controller.

Comment: How do you return the View in the OnActionExecuting method

Comment: @Jon -- my solution was to grab the source from www.codeplex.com and go to work.  This article is a bit dated might help: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx.  And, yes, the attributes can be applied both to controllers and specific actions.  You can even have multiple versions of the attribute applied if you set it up properly.  I have some controllers that require only authenticated connections, but have actions that are further restricted by their own attributes to require certain roles.

Comment: @Jon -- you set the Result property on the ActionExecutingContext passed into the method.